# Remote backup grabbing

Tags: rsync, incremental-backup, rsnapshot, backup

I have 2 servers. 1 is main. 2 is backup. I would like 2 to log in and grab files from 1 and backup on 2 with rsnapshot. Is this possible?

I was looking at the config setup and saw this:

```
backup_script  ssh root@example.com "mysqldump -A > /var/db/dump/mysql.sql"    unused2
```

That means that it will log into a server via SSH (not sure how to pass a password or key file) and copy/dump mysql into the directory unused2

EDIT:
After further research, I believe this is what I'll want right? This will dial into the remote server and copy files over? Still not sure how to load a password or key in yet

```
backup_script scp username@server:/home homebackup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ssh -i /path/to/key/file user@server
scp -i /path/to/key/file file user@server:/remote/location
```

Comment: With SCP you are connecting to a remote connection and copying files to your local connection, right?

Comment: No, with scp you are copying `file` to the remote server, to do the revers:   `scp -i /path/to/key/file user@server:/remote/location /local/location`